# trying to get an array of textview's to save in shared-preference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Right now I have a method for my recyclerview adapter where if the item is checked the phone number contained in that item will be used in a different activity. What I am wondering is if I select a few items how do I get an array of these number textview and add them to a shared-preference to be then used in a different activity. Here is my adapter where I can select an item and the number is added to the string:

```
 adapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<contact, contactAdapter>(options1) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final contactAdapter holder, final int position, @NonNull final contact model) {
                holder.contactName.setText(model.getContactName());
                holder.contactPhone.setText(model.getContactPhone());

                SharedPreferences prefs =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String check_state = prefs.getString( "state", "default");
                if(check_state.equals("true"){
                    holder.chk.setChecked(true);
                }
                else {
                    holder.chk.setChecked(false);
                }
                holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            holder.chk.setChecked(true);
                            for (int i = 0; i < adapter1.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                if (adapter1.getItem(i).isSelected(true)) {
                                    number = ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactPhone)).getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Inserted....." + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "true");
                            editor.putString("number", number);
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            holder.chk.setChecked(false);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "false");
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

As you can see I am saving the number to a string and putting the number into a share-preference which seems to work. Any suggestions on how to do this with an array?

Answer (score 0):

Add an "int" for your key while writing to shared preferences.

Something like this:

```
if (isChecked) {
holder.chk.setChecked(true);
int j =0;
for (int i = 0; i < adapter1.getItemCount(); i++) {
    if (adapter1.getItem(i).isSelected(true)) {
        number = ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactPhone)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Inserted....." + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editor.putString("state_"+j,"true");
        editor.putString("number_"+j,number);
        j++;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
editor.apply();
```

And while reading it back, reaqd them in a loop!

Comment: could elaborate a bit more please??

Comment: Sorry only seeing this now. will the data save like an array `{"086748328", "087463723"}`

Comment: You can use `editor.putStringSet()` to save as a `Set<String>`

Comment: do i still need the int j then?

Comment: in that case, you'll have to make a set of numbers. so, yes, int j is not needed then.